# Adding android support library v4 r13 to my android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, dependency-management

I tried to add the following library as a dependency in my android project:

```
compile 'com.thehayro:infiniteviewpager:0.4'
```

which gives me the following gradle error when I build:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.google.android:support-v4:r13.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/support-v4/r13/support-v4-r13.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/support-v4/r13/support-v4-r13.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/support-v4/r13/support-v4-r13.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/support-v4/r13/support-v4-r13.jar
         file:/C:/Users/Henrykvdb/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/support-v4/r13/support-v4-r13.pom
         file:/C:/Users/Henrykvdb/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/support-v4/r13/support-v4-r13.jar
         file:/C:/Users/Henrykvdb/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/support-v4/r13/support-v4-r13.pom
         file:/C:/Users/Henrykvdb/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/support-v4/r13/support-v4-r13.jar
     Required by:           
         xkcdexplain:app:unspecified
         xkcdexplain:app:unspecified > com.thehayro:infiniteviewpager:0.4
```

I tried manually adding the android support library and installing it with the android sdk manager but neither of those things worked.
I also read somewhere that I could try to find a download for the library and manually add it but there must be a more elegant way then that.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.henrykvdb.xkcdexplain"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.thehayro:infiniteviewpager:0.4'
}
```

**global/top-level build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I do not recall there being something called `r13`. Your library appears to be [this project](https://github.com/hayribakici/infiniteviewpager); that and the artifact have not been updated in three years. I suspect that you will have better luck using something more current.

Comment: Well my current project is already using the library as I manually added the classes instead of doing it properly by adding it with gradle. So switching to another library would kinda suck.

Comment: Since the library has not been modified in three years, it is unlikely to be modified going forward. You might consider just sticking with manually adding the module. Or, you could try using `exclude` directives to try to get Gradle to ignore that dependency, which you're satisfying in other ways.

Comment: @CommonsWare Maybe I'll try to ask the library's creator if he could update it so it uses a more current support library and if he doesn't reply I'll just use the manually added version.

Comment: @CommonsWare I contacted the creator and he told me he'll update it to the latest version :)